# Not getting correct javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing an e-commerce website,and i am a newbie also.
I had written a java script to increase the number shown in the text box when the button is clicked.
I am fetching the rows from database and putting the `div` tag into the while loop.
The `div` tag contains dish name,cuisine type,price, a text box which shows quantity, two buttons one for increasing the dish's quantity and another for decreasing the dish's quantity.
The buttons is shown on every div tag as every div tag shows information of a dish.
So when i click the button tag on the div of second dish or third dish it increases the value of first div instead of increasing the value of the respective tag. Help Me !

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      function increase(){
          var x = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
          x++;
          document.getElementById("quantity").value = x;
          
          var y = document.getElementById("price").value;
          var z = y * x;
          document.getElementById("price").value = z;
      }
  </script>
```

```html
<%
        while(resultSet.next()) {
    %>
    
        <div class="box box-primary">
        <!-- attackment block-->
      <div class="attachment-block clearfix">
          <!-- col -->
          <div class="col-md-6 pull-left">
                <img class="attachment-img" src="../dist/img/photo1.png" alt="Attachment Image">
                <div class="attachment-pushed box-tools">
                    <h4 class="attachment-heading"><a href="dishItemList.jsp">  &NoBreak; <%= resultSet.getString(2) %> | 
                            &NoBreak; <%= resultSet.getString(5) %>  | &NoBreak; <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Vegeterian Dish" class="label label-success">Veg</span></a></h4>
                  <div class="attachment-text">
                       <h4>
                           <i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> &NoBreak; <%= resultSet.getInt(3) %>
                      </h4>
                      <strong> Rating : 4.1 </strong>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.attachment-text -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.attachment-pushed -->  
            </div>
              <!--/col-->  
          
              <!--col-->
          <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-box-tool pull-right" onclick="increase()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
              <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right">
                  <input type="text" id="quantity" class="form-control input-sm" value="<%= resultSet.getInt(3) %>"> 
                </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-box-tool pull-right"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div class="input-group pull-right col-sm-3">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> </span>
                        <input type="text" id="price" class="form-control" value="<%= resultSet.getInt(3) %>"  disabled>
                        </div>
          </div>
          <!--/col-->
              </div>
              <!-- /.attachment-block -->
    </div>  
    
    <% } 
    
        connection.close();
    %>
```

Comment: If this has nothing to do with `java` and `mysql` I suggest you remove the tags.

Comment: Watch out, you're generating an `input` with the same id at every cycle

Comment: Please write a relevant title.

Comment: If you are confusing Java with Javascript you maybe should start with a smaller, simple project instead of trying yourself on an e-commerce website. Learning coding is a progress and starting with a really hard project where you need to consider a LOT of stuff (security and so on) right off the bat is generally a bad idea.

Comment: For your information: Javascript is **not** a Java script

Comment: i will take care of all these points from next time :)

Comment: I would say this *is* related to both java and javascript, as there's a problem with the jsf generating the list *and* it then gives problem with the javascript in the `increase` function.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Just because you'd have a similar problem in java doesn't make this question related to java, it's an entirely separate language and shouldn't be encouraged to treat them the same.

Comment: @LeeA. it's not that Java would have a similar problem, is that there actually *is* a problem with the jsp (hence Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the mistake you're making is that if you loop through several things and hardcode the id, several elements get the same id, which is why your increase() function is updating the "wrong" elements.

So you need to give each item in the loop a unique id. One way is to append an id from the resultSet to the id of the HTML element.

```
<div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-box-tool pull-right" onclick="increase()">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right">
        <input type="text" id="quantity<%= resultSet.id %>" class="form-control input-sm" value="<%= resultSet.getInt(3) %>" onchange="increase('quantity<%= resultSet.id %>', 'price<%= resultSet.id %>', 'baseprice<%= resultSet.id %>')">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-box-tool pull-right">
        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group pull-right col-sm-3">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>
        </span>
        <input type="hidden" id="baseprice<%= resultSet.id %>" value="<%= resultSet.getInt(3) %>">
        <input type="text" id="price<%= resultSet.id %>" class="form-control" value="<%= resultSet.getInt(3) %>"  disabled>
    </div>
</div>
```

The onchange should fire when the quantity is changed, and the function now receives a pair of specific fields that have unique ids. The function then just needs to do the math and make the updates.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function increase(qelement, pelement, bpelement){
        document.getElementById(qelement).value += 1;
        var dishQuantity = document.getElementById(qelement).value;

        var basePrice = document.getElementById(bpelement).value;
        document.getElementById(pelement).value *= dishQuantity;
    }
</script>
```

That just increments the value of the quantity field, and multiplies the base price by the new quantity.

This is not a copy/paste solution. There may be some JavaScript issues since I so often use jQuery. This is just a rough mockup of one way to achieve what you're attempting. There are more elegant ways, but this is probably the quickest to get something working. Once it is, you should use this as an opportunity to learn more about how JavaScript interacts with the DOM, and possibly even eventListeners.

Comment: how should i provide the arguments of quantity and price input fields.The function increase() is written on button's onclick event,so how should i pass the input fields quantity and price in the arguments.

Comment: You'll want to add an event listener for the change or keyup event on the quantity field. In that event listener, you'll want to get the id of the triggering DOM element. Then you could just do string manipulation to get the the associated price element, or use querySelectors to find the nearest, or a few other methods.

Comment: So if you have something with id="quantity34" and the price is id="price34", you'd call increase('quantity34', 'price34') somehow.

This isn't the most elegant way, but I'm just trying to get something working with the least amount of refactoring. Once it's working, you'll definitely want to revisit the entire scheme of how and why you're doing this.

Comment: Please tell show me the whole code,because i am not good in javascript.I just know the basic of it.

Comment: I'll update the answer with something more precise.

Comment: Its OK  No problem

Comment: I have tried something by myself and it worked. As you told that id should be unique so i added the <%= rs.id %> with both quantity and price and passed the same as the parameter of the increase() function like increase(<%= rs.id %>). Then attached that passed parameter with the name of the quantity and price in javascript like document.getElementById("quantity"+id) and document.getElementById("price"+id)

Comment: There you go. Also watch out that in your code above, you may be incorrectly increasing the price based on its current value. Check what happens if you change the quantity from 1 to 5, then down to 2.

Also, I'm guessing by your name that English may not be your first language, so do try to get your question title and tags more accurate as others have suggested. I understand that might be a challenge, but it will be very important for future questions.

For this, I would suggest a title of "Updating input fields via JavaScript updates wrong element" and the tags of "javascript" & "html"

Comment: Sure, i will take care of titles and tags from next time as this was my first question I've asked here. And also i have changed my code to increase and decrease the price,now it is accurate as per the quantity. Thanks for your help and support <3

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck on the web dev journey!